# Javascript create link from symbol in string

Tags: javascript, string, replace

here is my string

```
var text = "Lorem ipsum dolor *https://www.google.com/* amet, *https://www.google.com/*";
```

I would like to create new one like this

```
var newText = "Lorem ipsum dolor <a href="https://www.google.com/">https://www.google.com/</a> amet, <a href="https://www.google.com/">https://www.google.com/</a>";
```

My script not works. What I'm doing wrong?

```
var newText = text.replace("*", "<a href=></a>");
```

Comment: Learn about regular expressions.

Comment: Please read the following: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are replacing the first occurence of the asterix with `<a href=></a>`

```js
var text = "Lorem ipsum dolor *https://www.google.com/* amet, *https://www.google.com/*";
var newText = text.replace("*", "<a href=></a>");
console.log(newText);
```

To replace them all, you could use a capturing group (which will be in `$1`) and then use [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

[`\*(.*?)\*`](https://regex101.com/r/RiA7iv/1)

**Explanation**

- Match an asterix `\*`
- A capturing group which captures any character non greedy `(.*?)`
- Match an asterix `\*`

```js
var text = "Lorem ipsum dolor *https://www.google.com/* amet, *https://www.google.com/*";
var newText = text.replace(/\*(.*?)\*/g, "<a href=\"$1\">$1</a>");
console.log(newText)
```

Comment: hopefully there are no links inside the string to start.... In the example it would be fine, but if there is an image or something in the real stuff it will break.

Comment: var newText = text.replace(/\*(.*?)\*/g, "<a href='$1'>$1</a>");

Comment: This will add the links URL to the href parameter of the A tag.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the code below:

```
var text = "Lorem ipsum dolor *https://www.google.com/* amet, *https://www.google.com/*";
var arrtext=text.split('*');
var newtext='';

for(var i=0;i<arrtext.length;i++){

    if(arrtext[i].startsWith("http")){
         var link='<a href="'+arrtext[i]+'">'+arrtext[i]+'</a>';
         newtext=newtext+link;
    }else{
        newtext=newtext+arrtext[i];
    }

}
```